# converting graph api for xml

Tags: c#, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api, json.net

I'm having trouble converting a string of json facebook graph api, I used the facebook C# and json.Net.

But at conversion time it returns this error: **Name can not begin with the '0 'character, hexadecimal value 0x30.**

This is the code:

```
dynamic result = await _fb.GetTaskAsync ("me / feed");
FBxml JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode string = (result.ToString ()). ToString ();
```

Comment: Could you post the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Normal is the json generated by graph api facebook, this here is an example generated by my code: http://jsfiddle.net/btripoloni/PaLC2/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with portion of the json string as mentioned below (taken from your link http://jsfiddle.net/btripoloni/PaLC2/)

```
"story_tags": {
            "0": [{
                "id": "100000866891334",
                "name": "Bruno Tripoloni",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 15,
                "type": "user"}]
        },
```

Json cannot create class that begins with a numeric value such as '0'. Try creating the classes using the link http://json2csharp.com/ you will get an idea.

To solve this problem you can create a dynamic object and go through each properties OR create a `JsonConverter` and write your code in the `ReadJson` to convert the "0" to a meaningful name. May be this can help you http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization

If this is not your problem then update the question with more information like class structure of FBxml, call stack of the exception (from which line of the json code is throwing the exception), Json version etc.

Answer (score 0):

As keyr says, the problem is with those JSON properties that have numeric names. In XML names can contain numeric characters but cannot begin with one: [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) (see the *Well-formedness and error-handling* section).

My idea was to recursively parse the JSON with JSON.Net, replacing properties that had numeric names:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var obj in jsonObject)
{
    Process(obj.Value);
}

XDocument document = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonObject.ToString());

....

private static void Process(JToken jToken)
{
    if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Property)
    {
        JProperty property = jToken as JProperty;
        int value;

        if (int.TryParse(property.Name, out value))
        {
            JToken token = new JProperty("_" + property.Name, property.Value);
            jToken.Replace(token);
        }
    }

    if (jToken.HasValues)
    {
        //foreach won't work here as the call to jToken.Replace(token) above
        //results in the collection modifed error.
        for(int i = 0; i < jToken.Values().Count(); i++)
        {
            JToken obj = jToken.Values().ElementAt(i);
            Process(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

This seemed to work well, prefixing numeric names with `_`. At this line:

```
XDocument document = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonObject.ToString());
```

it crashed with an error saying that invalid/not well formed XML had been created. I don't have the actual error with me, but you can run the above code to replicate it.

I think from here you may need to revisit converting the JSON to XML in the first place. Is this a specific requirement?